# regular expression to replaceall substrings embedded in open curling brackets and followed by equal sign and digits

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

In the follwing String

```
String toBeFormatted= "[[LngLatAlt{longitude=-7.125924901999952, latitude=33.831783175000055, altitude=NaN},
 LngLatAlt{longitude=-5.401396163999948, latitude=35.92213140900003, altitude=NaN}]]"
```

1- I need to replace all "LngLatAlt{longitude=" **with open bracket "["**

2- also need to replace all the intermediate ", latitude=33.831783175000055, altitude=NaN}" **with ",33.831783175000055]"**

That way my string result :

```
"[[[-7.125924901999952,33.831783175000055],[-5.401396163999948,35.92213140900003]]]"
```

try it the following reg exp :

```
        String regexTarget = "(\\[\\[LngLatAlt\\{longitude=)";
        toBeFormatted.replaceAll(regexTarget, "\\[\\[\\[");
        String regexTarget0 = "(, altitude=NaN\\}, LngLatAlt\\{longitude=)";
        toBeFormatted.replaceAll(regexTarget0, "],\\[");
        String regexTarget1 = "(, latitude=)";
        toBeFormatted.replaceAll(regexTarget1, " ,");
        String regexTarget2 = "(, altitude=NaN\\})";
        toBeFormatted.replaceAll(regexTarget2, "]");
```

but it seems not working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `x.replaceAll` doesn't actually _change_ the string `x`; it **returns a modified string** that is the result of the replacement.  You have to assign that result back to `x`(or some other variable) or it's just lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
String result = toBeFormatted.replaceAll("LngLatAlt\\{longitude=([^,]+), latitude=([^,]+), ([^}]+)\\}", "[$1, $2]");
System.out.println(result);
```